# How to Submit a Struts 1.1 Form using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, struts-1

The Title summarizes my question, in essence how does one submit a struts 1.x form (html:form) using jquery. The form for struts to not have an "id" attribute making this perplexing.

Thank-you kindly

Comment: You don't need an id. You can get the form by tag name: `$('form').submit()`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `styleId` form tag attribute to give the form an HTML `id` attribute.

As also noted you can just submit the form, although you have many options for the jQuery selector, e.g., you could search up the DOM from the submit input or button or link for the first form, and so on.